# Flutter plugin development android src not opening after opening example

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-plugin

i am trying to make a flutter plugin for the first time i i ran into a problem.
I followed [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) tutorial to set the project up, i opened the `/example/android/build.gradle` file in android studio and it loaded and it also opened the `/android/src` folder. but then i noticed that i made a typo in the namespace so i deleted the entire flutter folder and regenerated it and after that when i tried opening the `/example/android/build.gradle` folder it didn't open the `/android/src` folder and only opened the example project

[image: Like this]

And if i try to open the `/android` folder in android studio i get a `Unresolved reference: io` error

I already tried restarting android studio, invalidating the caches, downgrading to android studio version 2022.3 and creating a new project but it didn't help

Any help would be appreciated.